# problem with tf tree, robot_pose_ekf, odom_combined

Tags: navigation, odometry, odom-combined, robot-pose-ekf, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've been working with a turtlebot with a kobuki base , i'm trying to use robot_pose_ekf but i found a tf problem,
in this case base_footprint will have 2 parents (odom_combined published by robot_pose_ekf node and odom published by
nodelet_manager node)
So  how can i resolve this problem, should i change some parameters in launch files?
Any help please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207148/problem-with-tf-tree,-robot_pose_ekf,-odom_combined/) by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you want to do this sort of thing you need to pick one tree which will be the primary and reconfigure the other frames to hang off as leaves.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-04-23**:
thanks for your response,

juste another question please:
i want to compare the trajectory of my robot with odometry (nav_msgs/Odometry) and odom_combined published by robot_pose ekf.

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-04-23**:
In this case should i change odom parametr in stack navigation with odom_combined or stack navigation should stay with the same topic /odom ((nav_msgs/Odometry) ).

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-04-23**:
so in this case i navigate my robot and i just compare the the result of two topics ( /odom and /odom_combined).
Thanks in advance

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-04-23**:
in another way I want to know if we send the navigation stack as goal (1metre). in this case if we work with odometry or odom combined the robot will walk 1 meter or the movement will depends on the values of the odometry?

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-04-23**:
finally
I want to know if the odometer is just a topic that shows the estimated position of the robot and displays it on a topic or values actually affects the robot's movement

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-21**:
If you have another question please ask it separately.